# Is there a better way to initialize struct from entries of a HashMap?

Tags: rust

I have a struct for connection info of PostgreSQL:

```rust
struct PgConf {
    host: String,
    port: i16,
    user: String,
    passwd: String,
    dbname: String
}
```

for now I have to init it from a HashMap<String, String>:

```rust
impl PgConf {
    fn init(&mut self, args: &ArgList) -> () {
        if let Some(val) = args.get("host") {
            self.host = val.clone();
        }
        if let Some(val) = args.get("port") {
            self.port = val.parse().unwrap_or(5432);
        }
        if let Some(val) = args.get("user") {
            self.user = val.clone();
        }
        if let Some(val) = args.get("passwd") {
            self.passwd = val.clone();
        }
        if let Some(val) = args.get("db") {
            self.dbname = val.clone();
        }
    }
}
```

I think the above code is a bit bloated. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Port should be `u16` since negative tcp ports are unheard of

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=211706623dd008756921091e486bdf9d thus your original code is not wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use `serde`, as @Masklinn suggested (for example, you don't want to introduce a dependency), and the behavior change in the code provided by @Simson is unacceptable, a simple macro can simplify the work a bit:

```rust
struct PgConf {
    host: String,
    port: i16,
    user: String,
    passwd: String,
    db: String, // Changed from `dbname` to simplify.
}

impl PgConf {
    fn init(&mut self, args: &HashMap<String, String>) {
        macro_rules! assign {
            ( $var:ident = $default:expr ) => {
                if let Some(val) = args.get(stringify!($var)) {
                    self.$var = val.parse().unwrap_or_else(|_| $default);
                }
            };
            ( $var:ident ) => { assign!($var = unreachable!("no default provided")) };
        }
        
        assign!(host);
        assign!(port = 5432);
        assign!(user);
        assign!(passwd);
        assign!(db);
    }
}
```

This macro is less type-safe since you can forget to add a default value to non-`String` entires and it will silently pass and panic at runtime. This can be improved, at the expense of making the macro longer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a nicely cursed alternative, you could round-trip through a type-erased serde implementation e.g. serde_json, then it's just a matter of:

```rust
fn convert(h: HashMap<String, String>) -> Option<PgConf> {
    serde_json::to_value(h).ok()
        .and_then(|v| PgConf::deserialize(v).ok())
}
```

though that requires some support, annotating the struct to start with:

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct PgConf {
    host: String,
    #[serde(
        default = "default_port",
        deserialize_with = "deserialize_number_from_string"
    )]
    port: u16,
    user: String,
    passwd: String,
    dbname: String,
}
```

and then implementing the relevant hook to get the processing you need on the port:

```rust
fn default_port() -> u16 {
    5432
}
/// copied from serde_aux as the playground doesn't have it
pub fn deserialize_number_from_string<'de, T, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<T, D::Error>
where
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
    T: FromStr + serde::Deserialize<'de>,
    <T as FromStr>::Err: Display,
{
    #[derive(Deserialize)]
    #[serde(untagged)]
    enum StringOrInt<T> {
        String(String),
        Number(T),
    }

    match StringOrInt::<T>::deserialize(deserializer)? {
        StringOrInt::String(s) => s.parse::<T>().map_err(serde::de::Error::custom),
        StringOrInt::Number(i) => Ok(i),
    }
}
```

There are cases where this can make sense, mostly situations where you're already using serde for that struct so all the "support" part is already there, and you just need to leverage it. It would not recommend it otherwise as it should be... less than ideally efficient. But it's one of those things you're glad to think of when they do apply.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to write this would be to create a functions which returns `Option<PgConf>`

```
fn try_create(args: HashMap<String,String>) -> Option<PgConfig>{
   let host = args.get("host")?;
   let user = args.get("user")?;
   let port = args.get("port")?.parse().unwrap_or(5432);
   let passwd = args.get("passwd")?;
   let dbname = args.get("db")?;
   Some(PgConfig{host,port,user,passwd,dbname})
}
```

If not all fields are present in the hash map, the `?` will return `None`. When all of them are present an unmutable object will be created encasulated in a `Some`

Or something similar.

Comment: You should make `args` mutable and [`.remove()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.remove) the entries, else you're trying to put a `&String` where the struct is defined to take `String`.

Comment: ... or `.clone()` would also solve this problem But I would use clap to parse my command line and there wouldn't even be a `HashMap` in the first place. I think `remove` could create a few more complex edge cases where some elements are removed if some other items were missing...

Comment: This is a behavior change: if one field is `None`, this skips all others, contrary to the function at the top.